# Mongoose schema virtual property logs Promise {<pending>} instead of value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am setting up a virtual property on my user model to calculate how many posts the user has but when I log the value in my mocha tests, it logs **Promise {}**.

I am not sure why I am getting this because in my userSchema.virtual route it will log the post count properly as "POST COUNT: 1"

I think I am returning the value wrong or something? How do I return the value so it can be read??

Thank you!

**Schema Virtual Property**

```
userSchema.virtual("postCount").get(async function () {
   const Post = mongoose.model("Post")
   const posts = await Post.find({ userId: this._id })
   console.log(`POST COUNT: `, posts.length). // correctly logs "POST COUNT: 1"
    return posts.length
})
```

**Test Code**

```
const Assert = require("assert")
const User = require("../src/models/user-model")
const Post = require("../src/models/post-model")

describe("finding user will auto populate postCount", () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const sarah = new User({
      username: "sarahsmith",
      email: "test@sarah.com",
      password: "sarahsarah",
    })
    await sarah.save()

    const post1 = new Post({
      caption: "test post 1",
      userId: sarah._id,
      mediaUrl: "amazon/s3.com/1",
    })

    await post1.save()
  })

  it("calculates user's post count ", async () => {
    const sarah = await User.findOne({ username: "sarahsmith" }) // WORKS

    console.log(`SARAH POST COUNT`, sarah.postCount) // logs "Promise {<pending>} ??"
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to await when reading the property like this:

```
console.log(`SARAH POST COUNT`, await sarah.postCount)
```

...since the virtual("postCount") is an async function itself

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you need to populate the virtual fields manually, as they will not be populated by default (see: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals).

This should work:

```js
const sarah = await User.findOne({ username: "sarahsmith" }).populate('postCount');
```

Comment: It actually looks like trying to access postCount without manually populating it is returning a promise that will fulfill with the populated value as well, so you could just `await sarah.postCount`, but I'm not sure of that solution.

Comment: David, I tried this but get the same result so it did not work..??

Comment: found the answer, it is "await sarah.postCount" since the virtual("postCount") is an async function itself